# Encontrar la diferencia entre dos columnas donde sus elementos son listas

Tags: python, lista, pandas

Necesito crear una nueva columna con la diferencia entre dos columnas, y además agregar comentario si hay que borrar o agregar el/los elementos, tomando como  referencia la columna 'Lista_OK'

necesito llegar al resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo del dataframe:

| Lista | Lista_OK |
| --- | --- |
| ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2'] | ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2', 'LNHOIF-4', 'LNHOIF-7'] |
| 'LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-3'] | ['LNHOIF-3'] |

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Lista': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2'],  ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-3']],
                'Lista_OK': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2', 'LNHOIF-4', 'LNHOIF-7'], ['LNHOIF-3']]})

df['difencia'] = (df['Lista_OK'].apply(set) - df['Lista'].apply(set)).apply(list)
```

pero con esto logro encontrar las que hay que agregar solamente.

me faltaría detectar las que hay que eliminar

En el ejemplo anterior el resultado seria.

| Lista | Lista_OK | diferencia |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2'] | ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2', 'LNHOIF-4', 'LNHOIF-7'] | agregar ['LNHOIF-4','LNHOIF-7'] |
| 'LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-3'] | ['LNHOIF-3'] | eliminar ['LNHOIF-1'] |

Espero puedan guiarme para conseguir lo que busco... desde ya gracias, saludos..

Comment: Si esa expresión te da las que hay que agregar, las que hay que eliminar serían: `(df['Lista'].apply(set) - df['Lista_OK'].apply(set)).apply(list)`. Dado que no publicas un [mcve] no veo una manera rápida de probar como armar toda la columna, eso ya te queda a ti.

Comment: @isvo justo venia a decir lo mismo que dijo jachaguate, pues esa seria la logica

Comment: gracias @jachguate agregue link de ejemplo...  la idea es poder llegar al resultado mediante una función que encuentre que hay que agregar/eliminar, saludos

Comment: disculpas recién pude agregar el ejemplo en código mínimo, @jachguate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes computar la columna diferencia valiéndote de una expresión similar a la que ya tienes. Para agregar los *textos* constantes a cada fila, utiliza el método `astype()` pasándole el tipo `str` en cada cálculo (agregar o eliminar).

En código, haciendo todo en un paso, luciría algo como:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame( {'Lista': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2'],  ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-3']],
                'Lista_OK': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2', 'LNHOIF-4', 'LNHOIF-7'], ['LNHOIF-3']]})


df['diferencia'] = 'agregar-> ' + (df['Lista_OK'].apply(set) - df['Lista'].apply(set)).apply(list).astype(str) + ' eliminar-> ' + (df['Lista'].apply(set) - df['Lista_OK'].apply(set)).apply(list).astype(str)

print(df)
```

Esto produce la salida:

```
                  Lista  ...                                        diferencia
0  [LNHOIF-1, LNHOIF-2]  ...  agregar-> ['LNHOIF-7', 'LNHOIF-4'] eliminar-> []
1  [LNHOIF-1, LNHOIF-3]  ...              agregar-> [] eliminar-> ['LNHOIF-1']

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

También puedes dividirlo en dos columnas, por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame( {'Lista': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2'],  ['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-3']],
                'Lista_OK': [['LNHOIF-1', 'LNHOIF-2', 'LNHOIF-4', 'LNHOIF-7'], ['LNHOIF-3']]})

df['agregar'] = (df['Lista_OK'].apply(set) - df['Lista'].apply(set)).apply(list)
df['eliminar'] = (df['Lista'].apply(set) - df['Lista_OK'].apply(set)).apply(list)

print(df)
```

Comment: muchas gracias @jachguate creo lo mas conveniente seria ocupar la solución de 2 columnas (agregar/eliminar).. saludos